# Looking for coat: shell front, fleece back

Tags: winter, jacket

Looking for a good fall/winter/spring coat. In my imagination it is: a hard raincoat type shell on the front of the jacket to block wind and fleece on the back to make it extremely breathable.

Looking to use it in Ottawa, Ontario in temperatures between +5C to -10C (although that is flexible, I wouldn't mind having to layer or figure out something cooler for warmer weather).

Bonus: It should also have some kind of reflective material.

Does this coat exist? Where can I find it?

Comment: See [this question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6724/looking-for-a-cycling-jacket-for-fall-spring).  The Derecho meets your needs for reflective material & water repelancy, but IME you need a base layer too.

Comment: I just responded to a similar question, might be of some help - http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7228/gore-tex-wind-proof-jackets

Answer (score 2):

Things like this are out there.  Look at the suppliers of mountaineering clothing as well as cycle manufacturers for innovative use of contrasting fabrics for ventilation.

I have an older model of this jacket:  http://www.patagonia.com/us/product/mens-wind-shield-pullover?p=24991-0-425

It treats me pretty well--wind-proof front, but with fleecy breathable arms and back.

I believe that, in Canada, MEC carries Patagonia clothing.

Answer (score 2):

[Rivendell](http://www.rivbike.com/) sells the [MUSA Windshield](http://www.rivbike.com/product-p/az4.htm), which covers the front of your torso. This could be worn over a fleece base jacket.

Answer (score 1):

In Europe, it is sold by [Decathlon](http://www.decathlon.be/NL/zwarte-fleecejack-3-193531273/#).

[You can order it here](http://store.btwin.com/blouson-3-polaire-noir-id_8181413.html) (I don't know if they deliver in Canada).

Answer (score 1):

I am using an [Endura Windchill](http://www.endura.co.uk/Product.aspx?dept_id=123&prod_id=218). Even though it does not fit your initial description, I have found it excellent for autumn/early winter use.

It has soft shell fabric in front, on top of arms and shoulders and even more breathable fabric in the back and under the arms. I have worn it with a microfiber liner shirt and a thin merino middle layer at approximately 0 degrees Celsius with good results. In slightly colder weather (around -5C) I replace the base layer with another merino shirt. I expect to wear it for most of the winter with merino+fleece layers underneath.

Water resistance is excellent, it does not get soaked through even after several hours of moderate rain. At the same time it breathes very well as it does not have a hard shell layer.

Answer (score 1):

ski gear.  water prof, light weight, bright colors, and WARM.  my BURTON jacket even has a pocket made for an i-pod, and loops for headphone wires. now how cool is that?

Answer (score 0):

When I used to row I had the exact opposite top layer - a [sleeveless gilet](http://www.rock-the-boat.co.uk/cat-2-subcat-5-product-12) with a fleece front and a shell back (highlighting where water typically splashed up at you). The gilet was long enough in the back to be able to be sat on while rocked over.

Given the hunched nature of the riding position when battling into a headwind in the rain, I've often worn this as the top layer on those inclement days.

Answer (score 0):

I love Ibex stuff. I have a vest similar to this - http://shop.ibex.com/Outlet/Mens/Momentum-Jacket

I own numerous ibex items and I would highly recommend them.

Wool on the back and the front is wind/rain resistant. In bright orange, it is highly visible and the $135 price tag for ibex is a steal.